# Permanently redirecting (`301`) robots.txt from root (`/`) to static files directory (`/static/file/robots.txt`)

Tags: 301-redirect, robots.txt

After reading up on [this Google Webmasters article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961#learn_robots_txt_syntax) on creating a robots.txt file, I noticed that they mentioned that the `robots.txt` file should **always** be at the root directory (`/`). However, I've been getting accustomed to putting all of my resource files (CSS, JS, images, PDFs, etc) in a static files sub-directory (`/static/...`) and perma-redirecting (`301`) associated links to them (in the case of meta-tags, etc).

1. Does my solution of redirecting `/robots.txt` to `/static/file/robots.txt` function as expected?
2. Even if my solution does work, should I still bite the bullet and do the proper thing and just serve the file as the spec tells me to do?

Comment: Why do you typically use a "static" directory?  I would never recommend doing that. Usless directories that make URLs more complicated are not good usability.

Comment: Where else would you put static resources? This seems to be the standard solution for web applications built in Node/Express, Go(lang), etc.

Comment: I put everything in the web root directory, I don't see a reason to separate files in directories by filetype because that is what extensions are for.